# The partial view to display a list I think I said that the parameters are null when it is not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I'm working on an application with Razor mvc4 utulizando and when I try to display a list in a modal with a partial view gives runtime error telling me that the list that happened in the controller is null. I do not understand because it gives that error if I have a **view** that is similar to the **partial view** and passed the same list of parameters and if I sample. Please help me with this, because in issues I clarify my doubt.

It is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Activos_Fijos.Models.ActivoFijo><table><tr><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.codigo)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.costo)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.descripcion)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.numserie)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.modelo)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.valorresidual)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.depreciacion)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.arearesponsabilidad)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tipo)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.estado)</th><th>Detalles</th></tr>@foreach (var item in Model) {<tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.codigo)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.costo)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descripcion)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.numserie)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modelo)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.valorresidual)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.depreciacion)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.arearesponsabilidad)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tipo)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.estado)</td><td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=item.codigo }) </td></tr>}</table>
```

And it is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult AFxResponsable()
    {
        PostgreNet bd = new PostgreNet();
        DataTable tabla;
        List<ActivoFijo> lis = new List<ActivoFijo>();
        bd.EstablecerConexion();
        tabla = bd.DevolverTablaCompleta("empleado", " e inner join area_responsabilidad a on e.id_area=a.id inner join activo_fijo af on a.id=af.id_area group by e.id, a.id, af.codigo");
        bd.CerrarConexion();
        int i = 0;
        while (tabla.Rows.Count > i)
        {
            lis.Add(new ActivoFijo { nombre = tabla.Rows[i]["nombre"].ToString(), arearesponsabilidad = int.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["id_area"].ToString()), codigo = int.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["codigo"].ToString()), costo = double.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["costo"].ToString()), depreciacion = double.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["depreciacion"].ToString()), descripcion = tabla.Rows[i]["descripcion"].ToString(), estado = int.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["id_estado"].ToString()), fecha = tabla.Rows[i]["fecha"].ToString(), numserie = int.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["num_serie"].ToString()), valorresidual = int.Parse(tabla.Rows[i]["valor_residual"].ToString()), modelo = tabla.Rows[i]["modelo"].ToString(), tipo = tabla.Rows[i]["id_tipo_medio"].ToString() });
            i++;
        }
        return PartialView(lis);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of your views?

Answer (score 0):

In the view where I call the partial the sintax of call is:
    @Html.Action("Metodo")     where Metodo is a method in my control class
My error was that y write:
    @Html.Partial("source.ext")